# Can I add a new upstream repository to my repository in a way that lets me merge from it?

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a local project that is based on some third party code. Unfortunately our local version was initially setup based on a tarball of the third party code and stored in SVN. Over time, it has also been updated with changes from the third party sources (via some exciting three way diff activity).

Our local code has been migrated to GIT (using GitLab as a central repository). Given that the third party code is also available in GIT I'm hoping it would be possible to integrate these two and effectively have the third party repository as an upstream of our local repository.

My naive thought would be to clone our local repository. Then add the third party as an upstream in my sandbox. I could then perform a merge from the upstream onto my master. (This would likely be from a branch of the upstream as we're a release or two behind). I can the push this to our repository.

However, if I'm right then it seems that this would only push my merged master and not the existence of the upstream? How would we go about adding the upstream into our central repository? If we do so how do we then perform merges? Do we effectively clone the upstream as well when we clone our repo?

I'm expecting the initial integration (merge) to be pretty hairy as the two repos effectively have no common ancestor. My hope though is that going forward subsequent merges would be much simpler and not effectively have to start from scratch again.

Summary: given two unconnected GIT repositories that effectively contain two (modified) versions of the same source code, how can I add one as the upstream of the other?

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about a fork.

Comment: Effectively yes, except the code was forked outside of git many moons ago and I'm trying to hook it back together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Summary: given two unconnected GIT repositories that effectively contain two (modified) versions of the same source code, how can I add one as the upstream of the other?

Setting upstreams like this is trivial.  Making the graphs *connect* is not: you will just get two disjoint subgraphs in your own repository.

Remember, Git is all about *commits*.  Commits have hash IDs, and these big ugly hash IDs are the commits' actual names.  Each commit stores the hash ID of its parent commit(s).  Branch names like `master` or tag names like `v1.0` are just ways to get into the graph, and to make commits *reachable* so that they are not eaten by Git's garbage collector.  For background, read through the site [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Note that the hash ID of a commit is a crypographic checksum of the contents of that commit.  The contents include the tree hash and the parent hash.  This means that the graph itself acts like a [Merkle Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) and hence validates the entire history, but it also means you cannot change the hash ID of any commit.

So, what happens when you take an unrelated (by graph) repository and yank it into your own repository is this:

```
your-root--o--...--o   <-- your-master
               \
                o    <-- your-branch


              o--...--o   <-- their-branch-X
             /
their-root--o--...--o---o--o   <-- their-master
             \         /
              o--...--o   <-- their-branch-Y
```

There are no common commits—the repositories were *created* independently; they did not merely start with some common clone and then diverge, so your root commit and their root commit are *also* unrelated.

This makes doing merges essentially impossible.

There *is* a solution, which is to graft the two graphs together.  Let's say, by some happy coincidence, that the two roots have the same (or sufficiently close) *snapshot* so that if we added a "super root" at the front, things would be mergeable:

```
        your-root--o--...--o   <-- your-master
       /                \
      /                 o    <-- your-branch
     /
super
     \
      \               o--...--o   <-- their-branch-X
       \             /
        their-root--o--...--o---o--o   <-- their-master
                     \         /
                      o--...--o   <-- their-branch-Y
```

However, we now run into the Merkle tree issue: if we literally add this node, we have to copy *all* the downstream nodes, i.e., all of your commits *and* all of their commits.  These new commits, made by copying (but changing something about) each of the originals, will have new and different hash IDs.

We can use `git replace` to add the node rather more figuratively.  This really does add the super-root node (to your repository) but does not actually make it the parent of the two existing roots.  Instead, we create two replacement root commits that have the super-root as their parent, and instruct Git to "look aside" to the replacements.  This method is workable, but has a drawback: cloning this repository does not get you the replacement objects by default.  (You can specifically ask for them as well and then the clone behaves the same way as the repository with the replacements.)

If whoever owns the "upstream" repository is willing to rewrite all of their history, and you are willing to rewrite all of your history, there's a solution to this as well.  If they are unwilling to rewrite all of their history, there's still a possible solution, as long as their history goes at least as deep as you care about: you can rewrite all of *your* history to base it upon all of *their* history, dropping any earlier history you had that they lack.

None of these are fun, but they can all be built up and tested using `git replace` to graft (with these replacement "virtual commits") the two disjoint graphs together.  Once you have a graph that is suitable for everyone to switch-to, run `git filter-branch` to turn the virtual graph into a new, different, physical graph.  All the commits that have a new history behind them acquire new, unique hash IDs, and now you can have everyone switch to the new repositories instead of the old ones.

Comment: I was worried it might be something scary like this. Rewriting upstream is not going to happen and I suspect resistance is high to rewriting ours. Given this I'm thinking I'm back to faking it out. As a followup, if I do force a merge from the upstream branch (I had a brief try on this and as expected much to resolve), would subsequent merges from upstream be easier as the trees are now linked?

Comment: Yes, or more precisely, it's possible: once you have a node (vertex, in graph terms) that ties the graph together, descendants of that node will find that node as a Common Ancestor. Git chooses the LCA (Lowest Common Ancestor, "Lowest" being in tree terms despite this being a DAG rather than a tree) as the merge base. Also worth considering: insert a temporary parent graft (using `git replace`) to make the merge(s) you need as LCAs, mark them clearly with commit messages (and maybe some annotated tags as well), and then remove the grafts as no-longer-needed.